# Keeps getting 403: youtube.quota exceeded without any usage

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We started noticing strange issue with the youtube APIs we keep getting the Quota Exceeded message without any usage,

When checked on statistics its showing 100% errors, so its confirmed that no APIs are successful, we tried by creating new key as well but still keep getting the same issue

[image]

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: check the requests column that's the number of requests you have sent.   If its not you sending them then it would suggest your keys have leaked I would delete them all.  And create new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LindaLawton-DaImTo, yes the request are getting sent from the app, but as Errors is 100%, so if some the requests were successful it should have been less than 100%, this is where we are having issue, and from app also whenever we tried we keep getting error.